# Measure the time taken by the program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the .exe of a program which has been generated from C++.

Is there some simple snippet which I could just insert to get the time taken by the program. I have the C++ code available but I don't want to tweak it much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line provided several solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [Boost.Timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/timer/doc/index.html). Code sample to measure time will be:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

boost::timer t0;
// do smth
std::cout<<"elapsed: "<< t0.elapsed() << " s\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to measure the time taken by some part (or all) of your program is to take a snapshot of the current time at the start and then subtract it from the current time at the end. On Windows, you could use the [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for this. I commonly wrap this in a little helper struct:

```
struct Duration {
  Duration( const char *name )
    : m_start( ::GetTickCount() ),
    m_name( name )
 { }

  ~Duration() {
    std::cout << m_name << " executed in " << ::GetTickCount() - start << "ms" << std::endl;
  }

  const DWORD m_start;
  const std::string m_name;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
int main()
{
  Duration d( "Program" );

  // Heavy work being done here
}
```

A little timing information is printed to `stdout` as the `Duration` object is destroyed.

Comment: It maybe ok for an academic code, but it's very bad practice to add output statements in a destructor, let alone application/computation logic.

Comment: @Neowizard: Absolutely agreed. However, if you just want to figure out how long some parts of your code need to execute (you can use this `Duration` class nicely if you introduce custom scopes to limit the objects lifetime) you don't want a nicely decoupled, modularized, dependency-injection-based profiling framework. You just want a little hack to do the job while you're debugging - it won't end up in the commit anyway.

Comment: I agree. It's a good an simple way to do some running-time related tests/debugging. Just wanted to point out it's not a good production idea

Answer (score 0):

On unix you would just need to prefix the executable command with "time", and if you by chance have [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) installed, then that's what I what suggest to use. Otherwise check [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is the very source of the process performance data on MS platform. It should be possible to do the trick with a pain of one extra method call before the app exit.