# How to handle large inputs in c

Tags: c

I was solving a practice problem on a site which states that

> The purpose of this problem is to verify whether the method you are
>   using to read input data is sufficiently fast to handle problems
>   branded with the enormous Input/Output warning. You are expected to be
>   able to process at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime.

Also how do I optimize input/output routines other than printf and scanf?

Comment: To read that much data, just do it in chunks of some size, using for example `fread`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread

Comment: sorry but i am a newbie and unable to get it can you please guide me or explain me a little bit

Comment: 2.5MB per second is not very impressive if you're using standard desktop hardware...  If that's a speed limit of your data processing (not the input), then even unoptimized I/O with buffered `fread` will handle that.  Input would surely not be the bottleneck in this case.

Comment: can you please help me how to use  unoptimized I/O with buffered fread

Comment: No. Please try to code by yourself and measure the performance. Ask us only when you did have some working code.

Comment: can you tell me how to find the run time of my program so that i can compare the performances??

Comment: On Linux, use `time` to measure the run time. Inside the program, use `gettimeofday(2)` or `clock_gettime(2)` or `clock(3)` or `time(2)`

Comment: You are unlucky. On Linux, things are probably simpler. I cannot help you (I never used Windows).

Comment: ya i think that i am unlucky but what should i do now to find the runtime on windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line

Comment: `clock` is a standard C routine, in the `<time.h>` header, that is likely adequate for the purpose of measuring a practice program like this.

Comment: This was closed hastily. Simply directing the questioner to the direct I/O routines in <stdio.h> (rather than the formatted or character I/O routines) would likely have been useful (and polite).

Answer (score 2):

It is operating system specific (because the C standard only knows about `<stdio.h>`). With Linux consider using low-level syscalls for efficiency, like [open(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [read(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html), [pread(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pread.2.html), [write(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html). You might also want to use [readahead(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/readahead.2.html). Don't forget to make I/O in rather large blocks (e.g. 128Kbytes), page aligned if possible. Read the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) book.

If restricted to standard C99 functions, use [fread(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fread.3.html) on rather big chunks. Consider also increasing the internal buffer with [setvbuf(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)

And 2.5Mbyte/sec is not very impressive. Probably, the bottleneck is the hardware, but you should be able to get perhaps 20 or 50Mbytes/sec on a standard desktop hardware. Using SSD would help a big lot.

Comment: Yes, unbuffered I/O with paged-sized (or slightly less), page-aligned chunks that are also a multiple of the disk sector size is a recipe for speed.  You have to make it worthwhile by processing that data efficiently.

Comment: i am new to c programming and don't know much so unable to get all technical terms

Comment: Try to code something. If on Linux, use `gcc -Wall -g` to compile it. Debug it with a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). Run it, and test it on large (megabyte sized) files.

Comment: i am working on a windows system can you tell me how to find the runtime of my program so that i can compare the performances