# cmd bat file - know instruction execution time

Tags: time, cmd

I have a bat script file with many instructions. One of them takes so much time and i want to know how much time the execution takes.

In Unix this is so simple with the prefix 'time'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions is to use the command

```
Measure-Command {copy *.* d:\dossier\}
```