# Plot python script performance

Tags: python, performance, plot

I want a plot that displays the execution time of a python script according to the input.
I have seen such a plot in [Haskell](https://github.com/kwef/Euler14-optimization), I wonder if there is any way it could be done in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux or UNIX run your script as :

```
time python yourprogram.py
```

For Windows see :

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, the question clearly asks for "plot". time command doesn't display any plot?