# Measure LAN Speed for Windows Home Drives

Tags: batch-file

We're in the process of migrating home drives from networked storage on one site to networked storage on another site and want to measure the current and future performance of accessing files.

The idea is to write a batch file that a user can run and it will output the performance results. The process would be:

1. Start time measurement
2. Open test .doc file (from current/future networked storage as specified)
3. Stop time measurement when Word opens and the file has appropriately downloaded (even if not fully downloaded)
4. Write out time taken

I'm struggling to work out how to tell when Word has opened enough to begin to display the file and therefore stop the timer. Can anyone suggest how to do this (or similarly for .pdfs), or tell me if this is entirely the wrong approach to measuring performance for home drive end users?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to measure execution time of command in windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: I'd seen the functions on that page for measuring execution time but my issue is that I can't work out when to stop the time measurement. If I just "execute" the .docx file, the time doesn't stop until I close it, and if I "open" the file, the time stops as soon as Word begins opening regardless of how downloaded the file is.

Comment: A Word document is a poor test for measuring throughput (for the very reasons you cited). There's an answer in that linked page regarding using repeated ping calls, or use an executable you can launch from the network location that simply loads and exits setting an error level you can test against to see if it loaded completely or not.