# Measure Elapsed Time to Run C++ Program

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, elapsedtime

I want to know the elapsed time taken to run my C++ program. For example, when I compile and run a C++ program like this:

```
g++ -o myprogram myprogram.cpp
```

then:

```
myprogram
```

How can I do this from the Command Prompt (CMD) without including `time.h` in my C++ source file? (I am using Windows 10 64-bit)

Comment: `#include<chrono>` and use its tools.

Comment: Is this good enough? Powershell is the default shell in Windows 10 now. [How do I measure execution time of a command on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4801509/962089) There's always WSL, too, with familiar commands like `time`.

Comment: @chris Just like `time` in Linux huh? I'm not the OP but you should write it as an answer. :)

Comment: @DeanSeo, the link that chris provides looks like a duplicate.

Comment: The C++ tag is not necessary. The question can be asked for a Visual Basic program too.