# CMD measure command execution time

Tags: cmd, command, execution-time

I'm stuck trying to print a custom command execution time. If I try to do something like this:

```
echo %time% & START "TestAgente" /W systeminfo  & echo %time%
```

I got same begin and end time:

[image]

I have tried with some combinations playing with delayed-expansion, but I think it fails (I guess) because in running 3 commands in a line instead of batch file.

Does anyone done something like this (without PowerShell). It has to be a single command line that someone could copy, paste and execute.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line) - even with the correct one-line-syntax.

Comment: I read that before posting, but I couldn't find a proper answer for my problem, sorry. Could you please tell me what's the proper way to fix it in a single line without using power shell?

Comment: Yes, answer was there. Sorry for duplicate.

Comment: `cmd /v:on /c "echo !TIME! & timeout 5 & echo !TIME!"` - by Nathan Herring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I measure execution time of a command on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Stephan said, the right way was in that post, and it worked!!

```
cmd /v:on /c "echo !time! & START "TestAgente" /W systeminfo & echo !time!"
```

Comment: Note: `Start` opens another `cmd` instance, which needs time, which gives you (slightly) wrong results. More accurate: `cmd /v:on /c "echo !time! & systeminfo & echo !time!"`