# What is the run time of this program?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

```
int f(int n)
{
   int x;
   if(n==0)
      x=1;
   else
     x=f(n-1)*2;
   g(x);
   return x;
}
void g(int m)
{
    int y;
    for(y=m;y>0;y/=2);
}
```

please say running time of the program with Recuurance relation. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are your ideas on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Approximately,

```
G(m) = lg(m)
```

and

```
F(1) = c
F(n) = F(n-1) + G(f(n)) = F(n-1) + n.
```

because `f(n) = 2^n`.

Comment: Yes, which is Theta(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your computer (and other things).

You could time the program yourself:
[on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line)

or with `time` on unix like systems.

Comment: I doubt that is the waited answer. I suspect that OP want to determine the big-O...

Comment: @Lasersköld: I think like Jean-Baptiste.

Comment: @YvesDaoust many guesses here. Why writing to me and not ask the person writing the question?

Comment: @Lasersköld: "with Recuurance relation" leaves little Douubt.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure, and there is a answer with that interpretation, upvote that then. Jean-Baptiste had already made your point with his first comment.

Comment: @Lasersköld: I may not upvote my own answer. Please do it for me :)