# Linux commands to detect the computer resource usage of a program

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

Suppose there are two programs `a.out` and `b.out` doing the same thing: sorting elements. `a.out` implements a `QuickSort` sorting algorithm, which takes `O(nlogn)` time and `O(logn)` memory, `b.out` implements a `BubbleSort` sorting algorithm, which takes `O(n^2)` time and `O(1)` memory. I want to gain some intuitive feelings of the time and memory comparison between these two algorithms, so is there any Linux command to measure the time and memory usage of a program after it is run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programatically, I would use `getrusage()`, which allows you to measure single functions, and in a lot more detail than just `time` or `top`.  For example:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct rusage start;
    struct rusage end;

    getrusage (RUSAGE_SELF, &start);    // get time at start

    some_function ();                   // Function to measure

    getrusage (RUSAGE_SELF, &end);      // get time at end

    printf ("System: %d usecs, User: %d usecs\n",
            end.ru_stime.tv_usec - start.ru_stime.tv_usec,
            end.ru_utime.tv_usec - start.ru_utime.tv_usec);
...
```

The `rusage` struct contains the following:

```
struct rusage {
    struct timeval ru_utime;    // user time used
    struct timeval ru_stime;    // system time used
    long   ru_maxrss;           // maximum resident set size
    long   ru_ixrss;            // integral shared memory size   
    long   ru_idrss;            // integral unshared data size
    long   ru_isrss;            // integral unshared stack size
    long   ru_minflt;           // page reclaims
    long   ru_majflt;           // page faults
    long   ru_nswap;            // swaps
    long   ru_inblock;          // block input operations
    long   ru_oublock;          // block output operations
    long   ru_msgsnd;           // messages sent
    long   ru_msgrcv;           // messages received
    long   ru_nsignals;         // signals received
    long   ru_nvcsw;            // voluntary context switches
    long   ru_nivcsw;           // involuntary context switches
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use time which will give you real, user and system times of the programs.
e.g.

```
  time ./a.out
```

The **top** command can be used for memory usage.

Comment: Or use htop which provides better functionality and looks nicer!

Comment: Take a look at clock() function for more accurate timing from within the programs.

Answer (score 1):

try `time` - time a simple command or give resource usage. The GNU version also reports memory usage:

```
/usr/bin/time --format="real\t%e\nuser\t%U\nsys\t%S\nmem:\t%M" -- ./a.out
```

Comment: How can I run the GNU version ?

Comment: It should be located in `/usr/bin`. You need to specify path if you want this version to run. Otherwise shell version of `time` will be executed

Comment: This commands works just as I expected, but cdarke's method provides single function measurement~ That's hard to refuse.

Answer (score 1):

For getting time of the program, you can follow the following link. It shows how to use `time` command.

[Get program execution time in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385408/get-program-execution-time-in-the-shell)

For memory resources, please look at the following link for how to use `top` command in linux.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

Comment: It seems there's no way to measure time and memory usage with just one command. Or have to write one myself.