# How to find the timestamp of the latest modified file in a directory (recursively)?

Tags: linux, bash, find, filesystems

I'm working on a process that needs to be restarted upon any change to any file in a specified directory, recursively.

I want to avoid using anything heavy, like [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). I don't need to know which files were updated, but rather only whether or not files were updated at all. Moreover, I don't need to be notified of every change, but rather only to know if any changes have happened at a specific interval, dynamically determined by the process.

There has to be a way to do this with a fairly simple bash command. I don't mind having to execute the command multiple times; performance is not my primary concern for this use case. However, it would be preferable for the command to be as fast as possible.

The only output I need is the timestamp of the last change, so I can compare it to the timestamp that I have stored in memory.

I'm also open to better solutions.

Comment: _upon any change to any file_ -> I also need to know about new files. Deleted files would be a bonus, but is not required. It's also probably much harder to track those. Doing a checksum of the directory would work, but would probably be very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just thought of an even better solution than [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30959873/4406793), which also allows me to know about deleted files.

The idea is to use a checksum, but not a checksum of all files; rather, we can only do a checksum of the timestamps. If anything changes at all (new files, deleted files, modified files), then the checksum will change also!

`find . -type f -printf '%T@,' | cksum`

1. `'%T@,'` returns the modification time of each file as a unix timestamp, all on the same line.
2. `cksum` calculates the checksum of the timestamps.
3. ????
4. Profit!!!!

It's actually even ***faster*** than the previous solution (by ~20%), because we don't need to sort (which is one of the slowest operations). Even a checksum will be much faster, especially on such a small amount of data (22 bytes per timestamp), instead of doing a checksum on each file.

Comment: Alternative checksums: `md5sum`, or one of the SHA family (`shasum`, `sha1sum`, `sha512sum`, etc.). `cksum` is fine in cases where security is not a concern (it isn't for my use case), otherwise `sha512sum` should probably be used.

Answer (score 8):

I actually found a good answer from [another closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory).

I've only modified the command a little to adapt it to my needs:

`find . -type f -printf '%T@\n' | sort -n | tail -1`

1. `%T@` returns the modification time as a unix timestamp, which is just what I need.
2. `sort -n` sorts the timestamps numerically.
3. `tail -1` only keeps the last/highest timestamp.

It runs fairly quickly; ~400ms on my entire home directory, and ~30ms on the intended directory (measured using [`time [command]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385408/get-program-execution-time-in-the-shell)).

Comment: ~400ms on 131,766 files & ~30ms on 9387 files. So, ~3ms per 1000 files.

Comment: Counted using [`find . -type f | wc -l`](http://superuser.com/questions/198817/recursively-count-all-the-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of remembering the timestamp of the last change, you could remember the last file that changed and find newer files using

```
find . -type f -newer "$lastfilethatchanged"
```

This does not work, however, if the same file changes again. Thus, you might need to create a temporary file with `touch` first:

```
touch --date="$previoustimestamp" "$tempfile"
find . -type f -newer "$tempfile"
```

where `"$tempfile"` could be, for example, in the memory at `/dev/shm/`.

Answer (score -1):

$ find ./ -name "*.sqlite" -ls
here you can use this command to get info for your file .Use filters to get timestamp

Comment: I need to track _any change to any file_; I don't have a specific file that I want to track with `-name`. I also need to know about new files.

Comment: ohh sorry didnt read it properly but this is even simpler as you just need to grep timestamp of the files in a particular directory and compare there timestamps. you can write a simple shell script for this following steps might suffice your task  1. Grep timestamps from all files from a directory 2. get it in one array and compare it to get latest time stamp and get corresponding directory

Comment: I don't need the timestamp of all the files, but only the latest one. _"The only output I need is the timestamp of the last change, so I can compare it to the timestamp that I have stored in memory."_ I find the accepted answer achieves that goal much more easily.

Comment: yes I got ur point. i am saying that u can write shell script for this purpose