# Python - Overcome import in timeit

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

I recently noticed the following about the `timeit` python module:

On my machine the lines:

```
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer(stmt='a = 2**3**4')
print("This took {:.3f}s to execute.".format(t.timeit()))
```

will produce:

> This took 0.017s to execute.

On the other hand writing a file **test.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

a = 2**3**4
```

and calling:

```
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer(stmt='import test')
print("This took {:.3f}s to execute.".format(t.timeit()))
```

will produce:

> This took 0.126s to execute.

And I'm wondering how I can test the execution time of `test.py` without changing the file itself. How can I work around importing the file (and therefore loosing time).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105845/650884

Comment: If it's the first time you call `import test`, python will be busy creating "test.pyc" and take a bit longer. Subsequent imports should be somewhat faster.

Comment: @Aaron: Except subsequent imports won't import anything at all (they go through a bunch of import rigmarole that eventually ends in pulling the cached module from `sys.modules`, which doesn't rerun the module at all).

Answer (score 2):

There is one problem with your measurements you are not measuring what you think you are measuring, when you write:

```
t = Timer(stmt= 'a = 2**3**4')
```

You are measuring binding time! Look:

```
>>> Timer(stmt='a = 10**5**4').timeit(100000)
    0.0064544077574026915
>>> Timer(stmt='a = 2**3**4').timeit(100000)
    0.006511381058487586
```

The timings are pretty the same but it is somewhat longer to compute `10**5**4` than `2**3**4`. The `2**3**4` is computed only once, when the code is compiled and this is called "constant folding", some optimizations which Python perform during compilation of your source.

Compare this two results:

```
>>> Timer(stmt= 'a = 2**3**4').timeit(100000) 
    0.00628656749199763
>>> Timer(stmt= 'a = x**y**z', setup='(x,y,z)=(2,3,4)').timeit(100000) 
    0.18055968312580717
```

But this acceleration is not given for free. There are two points:

1. Compilation time increases
2. `.pyc` file size increases (because this value is stored inside `.pyc` file)

Suppose I have two files:

```
#foo1.py
a = 10**7**7

#foo2.py
x,y,z =(10,7,7)
a = x**y**z
```

If I compile them with `python -m py_compile foo1.py foo2.py` the sizes of `.pyc` files on my machine will be:

1. `foo1.cpython-36.pyc` - 364 882 bytes
2. `foo2.cpython-36.pyc` - 150 bytes

Comment: That's really interesting, but I don't quite get how this exactly relates to my import statement? I was thinking, when I import `test.py` there already exists an `test.pyc` containing the constant, therefore the code should be faster than generating it on the fly (as for example in the command line), when in reality using import is slower.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to check out my [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877966/python3-using-timeit-to-measure-script-execution-time-externally) as well

Answer (score 1):

The closest you're going to get is to use `compile` with `exec` If you plan on running as a .pyc file, don't include the compile statement in what you're timing.

```
# time as if executing:" >python test.pyc " from terminal
#   (importing test.py will typically automatically generate the .pyc file automatically)
t = Timer(stmt='exec(code_object)', 
          setup='code_object = compile(open("test.py").read(), "test.py", "exec")')

# time as if executing:" >python test.py " from terminal
t = Timer(stmt='exec(compile(open("test.py").read(), "test.py", "exec"))')
```

This should get you close to the realistic timing for calling a script from the terminal. This does not eliminate overhead, because the overhead of calling a script is real and will be observed in the real world.

If you're on a linux based system, you can also just call [`>time test.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385418/3220135) from a terminal.

Comment: @StefanPochmann sorry, stupid typos. not thinking about what I'm doing. See edit

Comment: Ok now it works, but... it takes about 0.35 seconds while the OP's way only takes 0.15 seconds. Was it actually *faster* for you when you tested it? You did test this time, right? :-P

Comment: I want to time a script just if I put it all in quotes and put it as `stmt` in `timeit`. `>time test.py` always prints much more time, since python startup is included. How would I solve this problem? I want to test a some code `...code...` as if I used `print(Timer.timeit(stmt='code'))`.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to check out my [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877966/python3-using-timeit-to-measure-script-execution-time-externally) as well

Comment: @StefanPochmann it's not faster, it's representative of the real world