# Python3 - Using timeit to measure script execution time externally

Tags: python, python-3.x, measurement, timeit

Let's say I have a python script `script.py` and I want to measure the execution time of it just as if I put the whole script in quotation marks and used:

```
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer(stmt='THE WHOLE SCRIPT')
print(t.timeit())
```

I could do this by editing `script.py`, but I'd like not to. What I want is a second script `measure.py`, which can be executed like `./measure.py script.py`, which will basically do the above with any script as an argument.

How could I approach writing such a script `measure.py`?

Comment: why not import script.py into measure.py and you can call and time the function(s) you want?

Comment: I've pointed to that thread repeatedly, but you don't seem to be trying out different methods mentioned there. Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227180/650884?

Comment: Does `Timer(stmt=open('script.py').read())` not work?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Because often the script is really simple and does not contain functions only.

Comment: @Pavel I did saw your original comment to the second answer on that post and it was interesting, but didn't solve my problem, since I didn't want to edit the script and neither had a specific function to call. The answer you linked now is really interesting. The only thing I need to think about a bit more is handling the printing by the script (it'll spam the console, if timeit is called repeatedly).

Comment: @StefanPochmann This works really well thank you! Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: @user9115052 Meh... too obvious :-P. Feel free to post it as an answer yourself. Then you could also describe how well it works for you. I don't know that. Better use `with open(...) as ...`, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to pass some arguments to your `measure.py` script, you could use something like that:

```py
import sys
from timeit import Timer

NUMBER_OF_LOOPS = 10


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        command = [sys.executable] + sys.argv[1:]
        print(' '.join(command))
        timer = Timer(
            stmt=f'subprocess.run({command})',
            setup='import subprocess',
        )

        timing = timer.timeit(number=NUMBER_OF_LOOPS)/NUMBER_OF_LOOPS
        print(f'Mean execution time: {timing} s')
    else:
        print('You must provide a Python script path as argument.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above can be called using: `python measure.py script.py -argument1 value ...`

Note that using `open('script.py, 'r').read()` is correct and will close the file after reading it, since you do not assign it to a variable. The proposed solution (by @Stefan Pochmann) was:

```py
from timeit import Timer


t = Timer(stmt=open('script.py', 'r').read(), number=10)
print(t.timeit())
```