# VSCode terminal: How to display execution time?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, terminal

How to display execution time in terminal after running any program in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your operating system, [since VSCode's terminal uses your system's shell](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration).

On Linux and MacOS, you can use [`time`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385418/652669) before your command, e.g. `time sleep 2`.

On Windows 10, it seems to be [`Measure-Command`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513669/652669).

Also, on Linux and MacOS at least, you can customize your shell prompt to display the execution time after each command. You can do it manually or use a package like [Starship](https://starship.rs) or [Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k).

Answer (score 0):

this may be related to the terminal. You may want to be notified when a command is completed in the terminal. you can check [it](https://github.com/kaustubhhiware/NotiFyre) out for that.